# Using Selenium on Apache NiFi

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-nifi

Has anyone automated Apache NiFi using Selenium? I can't seem to find helpful guides that, its seems like a challenges because I believe its built using AngularJS and waiting for the elements to load is challenging when the GUI is not consistent. My main objective is to take screenshots on every processor down the line and outputs then later validate them, the struggle is the element load time (I like Java, not sure if going Protractor is the right route). Any tips or guides would be helpful.

Comment: Is using the web UI a requirement for your use case? Automating almost any task is possible through the Rest API that the UI itself uses. It is more stable across versions, so automation scripts would be less brittle.

Comment: Will the Rest API allow me to take screenshots? I assume the request are made in the background.

Comment: There is no call that let's you to take a screenshot using NiFi's rest API in the current version 1.6.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about screenshots being used as an output. What aspect(s) of the flow do you want to validate? Is the information in the screenshots the important part and the screenshots are just a mechanism to streamline some process, or are the screenshots themselves important as an output for some other use?

Comment: The screenshot is to verify the output of the attributes, make sure nothing breaks. I actaully solved the element load issue, I wait for AngularJS and/or JQuery to load before searching for the element (this is heavily used in NiFi).